# Eclipse asking for node.js

Tags: html, node.js, eclipse

As I right clicked on the WebContent folder of my project to add a new HTML file, eclipse warned me that node.js could not be found and that some of the functionalities might be missing.

It is not doing it anymore, it did it only the first time I right-clicked new.

I was wondering why it had warned me about this and only once.

As it might be something that many people know about or have encountered, I don't give any more details but I can if needed.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: There are now two HTML editors in Eclipse, the old HTML Editor and the new HTML support for the Generic Text Editor via LSP. The new one requires Node.js to run the HTML language server (see [my video showing this in action](https://youtu.be/XoUvOTiVaDc?t=586)).

Comment: Depending on the package, there would only be the "new" editor. The original editor (I'm not  a fan of calling it the "old" nomenclature) is not in the Web and JavaScript package.

Comment: @nitind Yes, _new_ and _old_ are the wrong terms here, since HTML support via LSP  in the Generic Text Edtior is not a replacement of the original HTML Editor, even if there is some overlap. I hope I made it clearer in my video.

Comment: I like the videos @howlger. I do think that most of the functionality is missing, though, instead of "some" as the message indicates, if `node` is not found.